# Existence of a curve

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that, for the '' curve '' $ x (x + 6) + y ^ 2 - 4y + 15 = 0 $, the implied derivation gives $$ \frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {x + 3 } {2-y} $$ Show that even though this result is completely meaningless, because there are no points on this' 'curve'.

Can you give me any tips? Because I don't know why this curve doesn't exist

Comment: Complete the squares for the $ \ x-$ terms and for the $ \ y-$ terms on the left side of the equation.  Can the left side ever equal zero?

Comment: The curve does exist in complex space as y=$2\pm \sqrt {x^2+6x+11} \mathit i$. Maybe the derivative gets you the derivative on the imaginary curve as a real value. This curve is parabola, hyperbola shaped on the imaginary branch and y=2 on the real branch, but is not one. Here is what it looks like:[Graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+-sqrt%28-11+-+6+x+-+x%5E2%29%2C+2+%2Bsqrt%28-11+-+6+x+-+x%5E2%29). When you complete the square, like @boojum, you solve and get this answer.